# webpy does not recognizing 2nd line of python in for loop

Tags: python

When I run the below code using webpy I get "NameError: global name 'test' is not defined"
When I run the code in strait python it works like expected. It is as if webpy does not consider the [$test = each] line as part of the for loop and causes an error. How can I get webpy to read the second line as part of the for loop?

```
$def with (orders)

<h1>OUTscreen</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Has Waited</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Customer</th>
</tr>

$for each in orders:
    $test = each
<tr>
<td>$test.minsInYard min</td>
<td>$test.size</td>
<td>$test.eqType</td>
<td>$test.cust</td>
<td>$test.trucker</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What happens when you use `each.XXX` instead of `test.XXX` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why this worked, but by adding 4 spaces after the second $ did the trick. thank you for all of your help.

```
$for test in orders:
    $    test = each
<tr>
<td>$test.minsInYard min</td>
<td>$test.size</td>
<td>$test.eqType</td>
<td>$test.cust</td>
<td>$test.trucker</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example you posted there's no reason why you can't have:

```
$for test in orders:
<tr>
<td>$test.minsInYard min</td>
...
```

The 'each' seems unnecessary (in this excerpt, anyway).

More generally, Webpy only allows arbitrary python code in templates where you prefix it with '$code', like so:

```
$code:
    for each in orders:
        test = each
```

It isn't sufficient to just put a '$' before the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignment isn't *directly* mentioned in the [templator documentation for web.py](http://webpy.org/templetor)

However, from what documentation there is, you probably need to wrap the expression in braces like so:

```
$for each in orders:
    ${test = each}
```

If that doesn't work I'd suggest it mightn't be possible. However, given that this is a template any logic should be done external to the template itself meaning assignment and anything more than non-trivial expression should be required.